# Where can i find free mapnik map styles with focus on waterways?

Tags: google-maps, mapnik, waterways

I am using Google maps for my map tiles. These tiles are very road oriented. As i am making an application for waterways i would like to change my map so that its main focus is on waterways.

I have a little bit experience with making custom map tiles with Mapnik, but it still requires me to make a lot of styling decisions and styling is not my strongest point. So it would be great if there are some free stylings available that let me render map tiles with a focus on waterways, like the ANWB (Dutch) water map.

I have found a site where i could change and test styles on the fly, but they had to serve the tiles and i think it also cost money to use their service. I am able to host such a tile service myself once i have the correct tiles.

Comment: Since it seems to me you are more or less looking for ANWB stylesheet for OSM maps, have you considered paying someone to prepare it for you?

Comment: @Igor, yes i have and will do if i can't find it somewhere and my own attempts don't match my goal.

Answer (score 3):

You might try Google Maps's **terrain** tiles. They better emphasize water, compared to the standard tiles, though their primary emphasis is the topography.

Comment: Most waterway maps use a very bright sort of blue for water, as in [example](http://noordersoft.com/ANWB-kaart.jpg)